# Join between Hadoop data and Sqlserver data

Tags: sql, sql-server, hive, linked-server, hortonworks-data-platform

We have data in Hadoop (HortonWorks) as well as in SQL Server. We have a requirement to join data between these two tables using the hive query. We have created a linked server to Hadoop.

The following query is working fine, But I am not sure if we could join to another server using linked server:

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(HortonHive, 'select * from xademo.call_detail_records;')
```

Also query with following four-part naming conventions is not working:

```
select * from HortonHive.xademo.call_detail_records
```

May be we could do joins with SQLServer only if the four-part query worked.

How do we query data with join between sqlServer and Hadoop (using Hive) with linked server?

Comment: What is your question?  If the first version is working, why is that not sufficient?

Comment: If you are looking for a more robust and generic solution, you should check out [Apache Drill](https://drill.apache.org/) and seamlessly connect your Hive with SQL Server with a pure ANSI SQL interface.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Edited adding the clear question at end .